# how to bind mat-option in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

hi I am begginer in angular, I want to create a dropdown list in angular material and bind it to datasource in node js ,
my html code is:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class = "tp-full-width" >
     <mat-label>product desc</mat-label>
     <mat-select >
           <mat-option *ngFor="let p of list_product" [value]="p">
                          {{ p.id }}
             </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

in ts have below code:

```
export class BasicComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    
  public list_product = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'description', 'action'];

  dataSource=this.list_product;

ngOnInit(): void {
      this.get_data();
  }

  get_data(){
           this.http.get<any>("http://localhost:3000/listp").subscribe(
          res => this.list_product.data = res                 //fill list_product from nodejs server address
      );
  }
```

but my dropdown list doesn't show any item of list

Comment: shouldn't you be using `let list of list_product.data`?

Comment: i see this link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/value-is-not-binding-in-mat-select-drop-down-if-it-is-an-object?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate through the array value list_product.data

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class = "tp-full-width" >
     <mat-label>product desc</mat-label>
     <mat-select >
           <mat-option *ngFor="let p of list_product.data" [value]="p">
                          {{ p.id }}
             </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.list_product.data = res` but in html "let list of list_product"?, it's wrong.
Please make sure list_product has value a Array